# render an associated object if the object exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, associations, helper

I'm trying to create a generic method on my helper to render the parent objects associations if the associations have been defined.

Here's some example code: The first method renders an association explicitly.  The next method tries to do it generically (this parent object has 9 associations, so I figured writing 9 render methods would be so not DRY.)

```
module SurveysHelper

  def render_demographics_part(survey)
    render survey.demographics_part if survey.demographics_part
  end

  def gen_renderer(part, survey)
    render survey.part if survey.part
  end

end
```

Comment: You can call directly into your view `render(survey.part) || content_tag(:p, 'No part found')`.  For every association you must define a partial named like that association. For exemple for `demographics_part `, you must have in your views a folder named `demographics_parts` and in that folder a partial that will be rendered when you call `render(survey. demographics_part)` name `_demographics_part .html.erb`

Comment: @Octopus-Paul, sounds like you're saying I have to render the parts explicitly.  Your example `render(survey.part) || content_tag(:p, 'No part found')` wouldn't work since survey.part is not defined.  It would have to be `render(survey.demographics_part) || content_tag(:p, 'no part found')` or did I miss your point?

Comment: I used `survey.part` just to be generic. Have a look here https://speakerdeck.com/carlosantoniodasilva/tricks-that-rails-didnt-tell-you-about-at-railsconf-2014 at 98th and 99th slides, for a better explanation

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
def gen_renderer(part, survey)
  if part.nil?
    content_tag(:p, 'incomplete')
  else
    render part
  end
end
```

I forgot that `part` is just an object reference - it doesn't matter what it is as long as it knows how to render itself (you need a partial in the object's view path for that - `app/views/demographics_part/_demographics_part.html.erb`)

It works, but there's probably a better way.